# prevent popup from opening new window in Ie6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, popup, hyperlink

I create a popup using *window.open* in IE6. Created popup contains a link to other page, which i want to show in the same popup window, but after clicking on the link, the target page is displayed in another brand new popup, so i have 2 popups opened at that moment.
How can i make a new page loaded in the same popup that holds a link to it?

p.s.

```
    a href="somepage.html" target="_self"
```

didn't help

Comment: Do you have a base target="window_name" defined for links? That would cause that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
a onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.whatever.com/'"
```

is an option ?